# How to load more data on screen without re-rendering the whole screen?

Tags: flutter

I am working on a forum that can generate more questions dynamically based on answers provided from questions before (For example if you answer question 3 by a yes, 2 more questions are added below it). What concerns me is that every time I "Show" a new question it would re-render the whole screen and thus making it inefficient. 
I have provided an example of a question that when answered would generate a text, this text would represent another question in my forum. This is the way I implemented, would this be inefficient (because of the whole screen re-rendering) and how can i make sure that only the "new" question would be rendered instead?

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StackOverFlow extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StackOverFlowState createState() => _StackOverFlowState();
}

class _StackOverFlowState extends State<StackOverFlow> {
  bool value = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Are you good?"),
                Checkbox(
                  checkColor: Colors.blue,
                  value: value,
                  onChanged: (bool) {
                    setState(() {
                      value = bool;
                    });
                    print(bool);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            value ? Text("Your checkbox is a yes") : Container(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your example ("for example in my code...") is not well-worded and unintelligible to me. You should probably try to clarify exactly what the problem is for you so that the question can be answerable. Right now it is not answerable.

Comment: any code you don't want to be reloaded every time the build method runs move outside the build method and create it in the initial state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it would not be inefficient. You should maintain a `questions` list with question data, and your `build` function should render the current questions. When you decide to add new questions in your event handler functions, simply add your new questions in `setState` such as

```dart
setState(() {
  questions.add(Question("How old are you"?));
})
```

and your new list of questions will be re-rendered.

This re-rendering is how reactive frameworks work. You should not try to go around this to create a "more efficient" solution. The widgets that you create in the `build` function are lightweight objects and Dart VM is optimized to create and destroy many of these very frequently. The actual UI elements are changed by taking a diff of the widgets that you create at every `build`.